# Thick/Jumbo Jump Ropes?

Tags: cardio, jump-rope

Does anyone have experience with a polydac jumprope? They seem to range from 1 inch to 2 inches and from 2 lb to 7 lb? I'm used to using a standard and speed jump rope, but these look like an interesting add to my routine: nothing like adding something new!. I'm assuming the timing and speed work of a traditional jump rope is gone but the required cardio would increase?

How does using these thicker jump ropes differ from a standard jump rope? Is there any potential for injury to the shoulder?

[image: PolydacJumpRope]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a discussion prompt/opinion poll.

Answer (score 2):

When skipping quickly with a standard rope, it's easiest to lift your feet no more than an inch off the ground, especially if you're skipping quickly. The benefit of this type of skipping is that it minimizes the impact on your ankle and knees joints. If you've been stung in the back of your ankles or legs by a weighted rope, it might make you jump higher. Over time, the higher jumps can cause pain in your leg joints, especially if you already have issues in those areas. Repetitive strain injuries are caused by making repeated movements, often with the shoulders, arms and wrists. Because using a weighted rope provides more resistance to your arms, shoulders and even your back, it's possible to injure one of these areas if they're not properly warmed up, if you have a pre-existing injury or you exercise too much. Avoid overuse of the weighted rope and if your body is excessively sore, switch to a lighter rope or avoid skipping altogether until the injury clears up.